# GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glGetIntegerv() with GLAD

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw, glad

I use GLAD ([config](https://glad.dav1d.de/#profile=core&language=c-debug&specification=gl&loader=on&api=gl%3D3.3)) to load OpenGL functions and [GLFW 3.3.8](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/releases/download/3.3.8/glfw-3.3.8.zip) to create context. Each time I start my program it pops a `ERROR 1282 in glGetIntegerv` from GLAD debug post-callback function (as far as I know it is invoked after each gl- function and prints an error if any occurred). I figured that this happens **after** returning from `main()`.

Here's the code (it loads OpenGL 3.3 and shows red window until it is closed, pretty simple I think):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    if(glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE)
        throw std::runtime_error{"Unable to initialize GLFW."};

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow * w{glfwCreateWindow(100, 100, "title", nullptr, nullptr)};
    if(w == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error{"Unable to create window."};

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(w);
    if(not gladLoadGLLoader(GLADloadproc(glfwGetProcAddress)))
        throw std::runtime_error{"Unable to load OpenGL functions."};
    
    glViewport(0, 0, 100, 100);

    while(not glfwWindowShouldClose(w))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(w);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(nullptr);
    glfwDestroyWindow(w);
    glfwTerminate();

    std::cout << "Hey!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Hey!
ERROR 1282 in glGetIntegerv
```

From this callstack:

```
#0  0x00416f91 in _post_call_callback_default_gl (name=0x446d40 <_glfwDataFormat+10036> "glGetIntegerv", funcptr=0x41c1ec <glad_debug_impl_glGetIntegerv@8>, len_args=2) at <glad.c>:45
#1  0x0041c265 in glad_debug_impl_glGetIntegerv@8 (arg0=33309, arg1=0x4526cc <num_exts_i>) at <glad.c>:1385
#2  0x00417168 in get_exts () at <glad.c>:220
#3  0x0042691f in find_extensionsGL () at <glad.c>:3742
#4  0x00426d12 in gladLoadGLLoader (load=0x402a2e <glfwGetProcAddress>) at <glad.c>:3821
#5  0x004016f8 in main () at <main.cpp>:33
```

Error 1282 is `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, but it pops up after the program ended (or at least after the `main()` ended). Even if I separate the whole code in another function (i. e. create and destroy everything in separate function), and then invoke it in main(), the error still appears after the `return 0;` from `main()`.

This did not happen when I used GLEW to load OpenGL functions, but maybe it was silenced. I didn't find anything similar to my problem on the internet. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to unload OpenGL or something like that?

UPD: Error message actually pops in gladLoadGLLoader(), **not** after the end of `main()`.

Comment: Can't repro on a Debian Bullseye box with Mesa 22.0.4 on a Radeon RX 6700 XT under X11.  What are you trying to run this on?

Comment: @genpfault Windows 10 x64, Strix 1080Ti (no overclock or anything), latest GeForce Experience drivers. I also tried this code on another PC with same Windows and ASUS 1060, error does not pop there. Seems to be deeper than just faulty code.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if it's glad's error handling callback that somehow triggers a gl function after the context has been deleted. Have you tried to add a call to gladLoaderUnloadGL before exiting?

Comment: @StarShine Didn't know such thing as `gladLoaderUnloadGL` exists, moreover it is not included in my generated GLAD code. Anyway, the error occurres on `gladLoadGLLoader()` i. e. when GL is being loaded (or more precicely when `glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS)` is called in GLAD loader), so doing anything after the fact must not have any affect on the error.

Comment: Ah seems I missed that last line in your post :) In which case you're right. It looks like this is GLAD debug version, maybe some asserts trigger that do not in release mode?

Comment: @StarShine Nah, the error is raised anyway (the code where this happens is the same), it's just not tested with `glGetError()` like it would in debug version. And also the fact that this does not happen on another PC (genpfault did not reproduce it and I did not see this on another machine) suggests that it's some sort of hardware / driver / other issue — **not** the GLAD fault.